# Why do i have problems with installing Node?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

When I was installing Node.js for react my antivirus said there was a trojan in a few of the files. So I deleted them. Node has been installed successfully but when I tried to check a node version there was an error. It only works in the directory in which I installed Node. I also installed npm and create-react-app. I decided to create a react app in that directory using npx create-react-app myapp(I've tried to change npx to npm too). It partly worked because it has created a folder with an app name and a package.json file. But it has lots of errors:

```
    E:\node-v14.15.5-win-x64\node-v14.15.5-win-x64>>npx create-react-app myapp
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm ENOENT
    at notFoundError (E:\node-v14.15.5-win-x64\node-v14.15.5-win-x64\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (E:\node-v14.15.5-win-x64\node-v14.15.5-win-x64\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (E:\node-v14.15.5-win-x64\node-v14.15.5-win-x64\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (E:\node-v14.15.5-win-x64\node-v14.15.5-win-x64\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npm',
  path: 'npm',
  spawnargs: [
    'install',
    '--save',
    '--save-exact',
    '--loglevel',
    'error',
    'react',
    'react-dom',
    'react-scripts@0.9.x'
  ]
}
```

I tried to delete Node.js but there was an error:[The windows installer service could not be accessed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkGro.png) I've tried these instructions but they didn't work: [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/-windows-installer-service-could-not-be-accessed-error-message-when-installing-application-2b29fc85-f5a5-3db7-08d8-cdc3b2e216d9)

I also tried to stop my antivirus but that didn't work

Comment: it says `npm` is not recognized.  Did you try just typing `npm --version` from the command line to verify that it is installed correctly?

Comment: Yes, it works only from the directory where i installed Node

Comment: Then you have a PATH problem.  Usually, installing node and npm automatically adds those directories to your system path.  Have you restarted your command session to pick up the new path since installing?

Comment: I suggest rebooting, then using the [troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d) to fix/remove broken uninstallers, uninstall node.js (as best you can) then re-run the node.js installer from scratch..

Comment: I tried to restart command session but i get this error:

Comment: Could not reset session services, Error code 5
Error [5]:Access is denied.

Comment: oof.  Sounds like you have bigger problems to resolve before fixing node.js  Maybe this is a [superuser](https://superuser.com/) question?

Comment: Troubleshooter worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The [Program Install and Uninstall troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d) is a tool provided by Microsoft that can fix problems that block programs from being installed or removed.

Use that tool to remove the broken Node.js uninstaller, then reinstall Node.js from [the official site](https://nodejs.org/).